# Set default value after form submit in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to set a cell to a default value as soon as a form is submitted to a spreadsheet (I want to add a value after the last value from that the spreadsheet gives me).
Since upon a form submit it erases all the values in the row, I can't have a formula in this cell, I think I'd have to do it with AppScripts.
I tried doing it with onFormSubmit but I did not get very far with it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this `Since upon a form submit it erases all the values in the row, I can't have a formula in this cell,`

Comment: Can you provide more information about what exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "set a cell to a default value"? Moreover, can you share the code you have used as well?

Answer (score 1):

If the formula is going to be the same for each row, you could add an ARRAYFORMULA version of your formula in the second row of your Responses sheet. By putting your formula in the second row you can still add a header to that column.

For example, if you wanted to get the first three characters of whatever is in Column B, in the second row of the column you want your formula in (in your Form Responses sheet), you could use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="","",LEFT(B2:B,3)))
```

If it's just a default value you want in that column, then use something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="","",your_default_value))
```

Good luck!